# Can Google Safe Browsing work on the domains instead of URLs?

Tags: google-chrome, safe-browsing

I would like to use Google safe browsing to find malicious domains, and I doubt that it reports the whole domain(like example.com) as malicious if only a specific path in the domain (example.com/path1/maliciousfile.html) is malicious. So if I check the domain example.com, it returns nothing (means the domain is clean). Are my assumptions true? if yes, Is there a way that I can check if there exists a malicious  path in a given domain (without knowing the specific malicious path).

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

As I understood from the documentation, it just checks against list of URLs.